# How can I invite facebook friends like Sounds app did?

Tags: facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I saw that [Sounds](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vimies.getsoundsapp) app can invite all my Facebook friends to install this application by press only one OK button. [image]

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 3):

Detailed information about the use of invitations to the application here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites

Comment: Yes I known it. But I must to call `AppInviteDialog` and pick friends from there. But `Sounds` app just press one button.

Comment: It would help if you showed us what happens after the button is clicked and what the recipients receive on their Facebook profiles